# nginx sent_http header variable not truthy

Tags: http, nginx

I would like nginx to change its behavior based on a response header from a backend.

My backend (also nginx) returns a `Foo` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.5
Foo: true
```

If the `Foo` header is set, I would like to change the behavior.

If I use the following config, `$sent_http_foo` doesn't appear to be truthy and the header isn't set.

```
if ($sent_http_foo) {
  add_header "Foo-Header-Set" "true";
}
```

However, if I use this config instead:

```
add_header "Foo-Header-Value" "$sent_http_foo";
```

I see the new header with true in my response.

Is it possible to use the `$sent_http_*` variables in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an old mailing list but it is related to your question - [Nginx mailing](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2013-December/041465.html)

In the mailing list you can read -

> Both "set" and "if" directives you mentioned are executed *before* 
>   a request is sent to upstream.
>   and at this point there is no foo header in the response.... 
>   "if" or "set" directives isn't going to work, and this is what 
>   causes behavior you see.

Moreover, you can read further about [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

> Directive if has problems when used in location context, in some cases it doesn’t do what you expect but something completely different instead. In some cases it even segfaults. It’s generally a good idea to avoid it if possible.

In conclusion - the way you do is totally fine:

`add_header "Foo-Header-Value" "$sent_http_foo";`

Comment: So I guess what I'm trying to do here might not actually be possible with plain NGINX. Perhaps a slightly odd requirement, but I was trying to block requests when the backend returns a certain header (block as in return a 4XX).

Comment: @CharlieEgan why don't you just have the backend return 4xx directly?

Comment: @CharlieEgan - AFAIK you don't have this in the plain NGINX. 
You can create your module that uses [headers_out](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/headers_management/) that checks the content of this header and return 4XX. This can help you [NGINX Tutorial: Developing Modules](http://www.airpair.com/nginx/extending-nginx-tutorial) but I think you need a good reason to go to that direction.

Comment: @cnst this is as a generic solution for a number of legacy backends that I don't have control over.

Comment: @GalS thanks for the extra info & answer above. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CharlieEgan - Sure